# Turn off autocomplete for single webpage

Tags: google-chrome, html, autocomplete, auto-form-fill

I use a webpage for work which I have several logins for (admin, user, etc) so I utilize Chrome autocomplete for my logins. However, when I create a new user for the system, it autofills my user name in the "Phone Number" field, and my password in the password field intended for the new users password.

Is there a way to disable autocomplete just for these fields so that it does not happen every time I add a new user or edit a current one? I am no expert on HTML, so I have no idea if this can be changed as a visitor to a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) (works with most browsers), just need to add the following to your form element:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

You can add it to the whole form, example:

```
<form method="post" action="/form" autocomplete="off">
[…]
</form>
```

Or to a single element:

```
<input type="text" id="cc" name="cc" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
autocomplete="off" will work for sure either you implement it with form as mentioned below or any single element of input field.
```

**for form**

```
<code><form id="submitForm" method="post" action="/formSubmit" autocomplete="off"></code>
```

For single element:

```
<input type="text" id="autoComplete" name="username" autocomplete="off">
```

**try it it will work 100%.**